# Only Log a Call Action will Display in Actions & Recommendations Component Regardless of Configuration

Tags: deployment, quickaction, component

Regardless of what configuration I do and what global actions or flows I assign to channels in the Actions & Recommendations deployment menu, it only ever shows the Log a Call action. If I click add, it shows a custom action I created and the Create Task action. I've tried to configure recommendations and playing around with the Guided Actions component, but nothing seems to have an effect on what actions are pinned, mandatory, etc. by default. Can someone help? What I am missing here?

Note, I do not have Einstein. Do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

The channel how the record is opened is the driver for the different configurations (Chat, Phone and Default). Test with the `Default` one and access the records from a list view or a lookup. Here is an example using 3 mandatory actions in the layout and allowing only two actions to add:

[image]

I made sure the Global actions were correctly assigned in my Publisher Layout prior to testing.